# ng2-Pagination in Angular 2

Tags: angular, pagination

i am following a documentation on how to implement ng2-pagination in angular 2 . Below is my code. However, i am falling into bit of errors showing in my terminal. What could i be doing wrongly? My angular version is 2.3.0

**table.html**

```
  <tr>

    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Continent</th>
</tr>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let key of Country | keys | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 10 , currentPage: page}; let i = index" >
      <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{Country[key].name}}</td>
      <td>{{Country[key].continent}}</td>

     </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
<div class="has-text-centered">
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page = $event"></pagination-controls>
</div>
```

**component**

```
 Component({

        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush



    })


    export class CountryComponent {

        @Input('data') Country:string[] =[];
        page: number = 1;

        //store incoming data

        Country: Country[] = [];
constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private router: Router) {



        this.httpService.getCountry()
            .subscribe(data => {
                    this.Country = data;
                }
            );

    }
```

**error**

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForPaginate' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("

  <tbody>
    <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let key of Country | keys  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 10 , currentPage: page}; let i = index" >"): CountryComponent@92:8
Property binding ngForPaginate not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
```

Comment: Might it be, that it does not like the `keys` pipe in there? Try with some dummy data that does not need that pipe and see if that works. I have used the same pagination , and I really don't see anything else obvious that would cause that error? This is just a wild guess, worth a try, but I don't reaaally see why that would matter, but....

Comment: Without the keys, it works perfectly with the application

Comment: Well... then apparently it does not work with another pipe present, which is not good of course. And your keys pipe works as should without the pagination? Maybe raise an issue in the github project if that is the case? I don't think anyone can really help, if it's because of the `keys` pipe that it's not working... You'd need to try another package or change your `Country` to not need the pipe... Not muvch more I can say, sorry :(

Comment: is there any other pagination package that i could try?

Comment: I couldn't say, haven't tried others. I guess you just have to ask google for this answer. "Angular 2 pagination" search words gives some suggestions...

Comment: I found an answer to it @AJT_82

Comment: Great! To this specific question and ng2-pagination? If you did, consider posting an answer, might help others :) But of course if it is a different solution, then answer is not suitable.

Comment: An answer to this same question. Hopes my answer helps others. Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.npm install ng2-pagination --save

2.import {Ng2PaginationModule} from 'ng2-pagination'; //importing ng2-pagination into your app.module.ts file

@NgModule({
  imports: [Ng2PaginationModule ]

```
<tr>

    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Continent</th>
</tr>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let key of Country | keys | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 10 , currentPage: page}; let i = index" >
      <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{Country[key].name}}</td>
      <td>{{Country[key].continent}}</td>

     </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="page = $event" id="1"
                      maxSize="5"
                      directionLinks="true"
                     >
                </pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<tr *ngFor="let key of (Country | keys | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 10 , currentPage: page}); let i = index" >
```

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let key of ( Country | keys | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 10 , currentPage: page}); let i = index" >